# Android: CardViews overlapping within RecyclerView when animation is toggled while scrolling

Tags: java, android, animation, mobile

That title was sort of a mouthful. Basically, I have these CardViews within a RecyclerView. I have a faux animation to expand and shrink the CardViews when they're clicked. I do this by setting various elements inside them to View.GONE or View.VISIBLE depending on if the card is expanded or not.

Here is the code for expanding/collapsing the cards:

```
    // Expand the CardView
    private boolean expand(View cardView) {
        // Make the shortened ("intro") text invisible and make the full text visible
        mIntroTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mExpandableIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCollapseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }

    // Collapse the CardView
    private boolean collapse(View cardView) {
        // Make the shortened ("intro") text visible and make the full text invisible
        mInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCollapseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mExpandableIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mIntroTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
```

It works fine except if I tap a card while scrolling, the card will move out of place, overlapping with other cards as shown in these pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfetM.jpg

I can provide other code if needed.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to notify the recycler view that the card view will change size mid scroll. I don't have anything to back this up, it's just a hunch

Comment: How do I go about notifying the RecyclerView that the Cards will change size mid-scroll?

Comment: requestLayout

Seems like a candidate for such a notification. Beware of it's caveats, read the docs properly